# Google Analytics v4 not counting

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to integrate gav 4 in my app.I followed the tutorial but analytics not counting my stats.

This is my class:

```
public class Trackers extends Application
{
    public enum TrackerName
    {
        APP_TRACKER,
        GLOBAL_TRACKER, 
        ECOMMERCE_TRACKER,
    }

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId)
    {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId))
        {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            if( trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER )
            {
                Log.w("Anal","ok");
                mTrackers.put(trackerId, analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker));
            }
        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }
}
```

global_tracker.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">


    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
    <screenName name="com.impact.ribony.MainActivity">MainActivity</screenName>
    <!--  The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXX-X</string>
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>
    <string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>
</resources>
```

And onStart() method:

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Tracker t = ((Trackers)      getApplication()).getTracker(Trackers.TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER);
    t.setScreenName("Main");
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
}
```

Mainifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxxxx.xxxxx"
    android:versionCode="8"
    android:versionName="1.0.7" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:name=".Trackers"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ribony_top_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
            android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
                    <meta-data
    android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
    android:value=".MainActivity" />

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
</intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

This is the logs:

```
11-07 09:30:40.293: V/GAV4(1520): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connect: bindService returned false for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) }
11-07 09:30:40.293: W/GAV4(1520): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), will retry.
11-07 09:30:40.293: I/GAV4(1520): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
11-07 09:30:40.293: V/GAV4(1520): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Initialized GA Thread
11-07 09:30:40.293: V/GAV4(1520): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
11-07 09:30:40.293: V/GAV4(1520): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
11-07 09:30:40.293: V/GAV4(1520): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
11-07 09:30:45.297: V/GAV4(1520): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
11-07 09:30:45.297: V/GAV4(1520): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: connect: bindService returned false for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) }
11-07 09:30:45.297: V/GAV4(1520): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: falling back to local store
11-07 09:30:45.297: V/GAV4(1520): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to store  PATH: https:  PARAMS: v=1,  ul=en-us,  t=screenview,  ht=1415352635299,  sr=1080x1776,  a=2097658927,  an=Ribony,  tid=UA-42075172-3,  aid=com.impact.ribony,  cid=972936b4-4a71-4418-ba4a-e77cb965702d,  av=1.0.7,  _u=.nKK-AL,  cd=Main,  
11-07 09:30:45.297: W/GAV4(1520): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), using local store.
11-07 09:30:45.305: V/GAV4(1520): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: PowerSaveMode initiated.
11-07 09:30:45.313: V/GAV4(1520): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: PowerSaveMode terminated.
11-07 09:30:45.313: V/GAV4(1520): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Dispatch running...
11-07 09:30:45.317: V/GAV4(1520): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/3.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; Samsung Galaxy S5 - 4.4.2 - API 19 - 1080x1920 Build/KOT49H)
11-07 09:30:45.317: V/GAV4(1520): Host: ssl.google-analytics.com
11-07 09:30:45.317: V/GAV4(1520): GET /collect?ul=en-us&ht=1415352635299&sr=1080x1776&a=2097658927&aid=com.impact.ribony&cid=972936b4-4a71-4418-ba4a-e77cb965702d&av=1.0.7&v=1&t=screenview&an=Ribony&tid=UA-42075172-3&_u=.nKK-AL&_v=ma4.0.3&cd=Main&qt=10025&z=65 HTTP/1.1
11-07 09:30:46.029: V/GAV4(1520): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: sent 1 of 1 hits
11-07 09:30:46.037: V/GAV4(1520): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: PowerSaveMode initiated.
```

I am looking to my panel and I can't see any activity. (Also I looked the real time reports and it was empty.)

Where is the problem ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: How long ago did you create the Google analytics account?  It can take up to 48 hours for a new account to start recording data.

Comment: I created 24 hours ago.But I have another account when use the second account (I created it 5 months ago) I see only real time analytics,I couldn't see another analytics.I was using the same code.What do you think about my code is everything okay ?

Comment: It takes 24 hours for data to move from real-time to standard reports.   I would assume your code is fine if you are seeing real-time data on the second account.

Comment: I waited 1 week on another account and I couldn't see real time reports.I can show you:http://prntscr.com/53v82s and real time : http://prntscr.com/53v87m I captured now.